# List<string> with dynamic number of elements and dynamic key names

Tags: c#, list

I want a List with dynamic Key names.

I have following model:

```
public class PlaceTime
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Place { get; set; }
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeTo { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with following data:

```
1, NewYork, 1/1/2015, 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM, Matt
2, NewYork, 1/1/2015, 8:00 AM, 10:00 AM, Ann
3, NewYork, 1/1/2015, 12:00 AM, 14:00 AM, Tom
4, NewYork, 1/1/2015, 15:00 AM, 18:00 AM, Matt
```

And as a result I want for example following List:

```
List<?> dynamicList;
dynamic[0]: Key = "Place", Value = "New York"
dynamic[0]: Key = "Day", Value = "1/1/2015"
dynamic[0]: Key = "8:00 AM - 10:00 AM", Value = "Matt & Ann"
dynamic[1]: Key = "Place", Value = "New York"
dynamic[1]: Key = "Day", Value = "1/1/2015"
dynamic[1]: Key = "12:00 AM - 14:00 AM", Value = "Tom"
dynamic[2]: Key = "Place", Value = "New York"
dynamic[2]: Key = "Day", Value = "1/1/2015"
dynamic[2]: Key = "15:00 AM - 18:00 AM", Value = "Matt"
```

How do I create a List with a dynamic number of elements (depending of the TimeFrom/TimeTo combinations stored in PlaceTime model) with key names depending on the values in the model?

Comment: `List<PlaceTime>` ? Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Your question is Unclear.

Comment: There actually aren't a question, just some code and a bit of description.. Please specify :)

Comment: unclear question, specify what you mean and want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a way to do it. With a list that contains dynamic dictionaries with key value pairs.

I am not sure if it is the best way, but it gets the work done.

Code picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLkgP.png